# cygwin +windows download android resource

Tags: android, cygwin

I used cygwin at windows to download android resource as ;http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html  but when i run the `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1`  it give me:

```
File "/opt/android/bin/repo", line 595, in 
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/android/bin/repo", line 562, in main
    _Init(args)
  File "/opt/android/bin/repo", line 181, in _Init
    _CheckGitVersion()
  File "/opt/android/bin/repo", line 210, in _CheckGitVersion
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**EDIT:** The original questioner left the following as an answer:

I solved it: my cygwin did not download git, so I downloaded git in cygwin, all is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isolveit，because my cygwin not download git,so i download in the cygwin,all is  ok